# How 2's complement of -128 in Bit representation for 8 bit register is 1000 0000?

Tags: signed, complement

I have got a basic question for signed number representation in computer 
Q) As i have learned in a 8-bit representation the 7th bit ( count from 0-7) is always the sign bit and the remaining 0-6 bits are the magnitude of the number

so in case of negative number 7th bit always be 1. 
Then how is -128 equal to 1000 0000??

As we see 1000 0000 this we assume its a negative number and take 000 0000 to be magnitude .. and if take the 2's complement for this it comes to be 1000 0000

so does in this case does the sign bit get overwritten in 8-bit register .. please explain someone .. hope i am clear at my explanation

Answer (score 0):

In twos complement, when the top bit is 1, the number is - (the inverted number + 1)

So for the example of  1000 0000 (assuming we have 8 bit numbers), that is - (inverted 1000 0000  + 1) = - (0111 1111 + 1) = - (127 + 1) = -128

To create a twos complement of a negative decimal number, you do a similar thing - for a given number invert the bits, and then add 1.

Ie: For -5, the 5 is 0000 0101 (assuming we will be an 8 bit number). Inverted 1111 1010, add 1 = 1111 1011.

For -128, the 128 is 1000 0000 (ignoring the fact at the moment that the top bit would mean -ve for the 8 bit number), Inverted = 0111 1111, add 1 = 1000 0000.

Comment: hello lostbard , Thanks for the explanation can you please explain in detail the last statement for -128.  i really could not get how does is store s in computer by ignoring the overflow